# ios9 mobile safari landscape css bug with position:absolute bottom:0

Tags: ios, css, html, mobile-safari, landscape

I cannot seem to find the workaround for this.

On ios9 in mobile safari, if a webapp uses `position:absolute` and `bottom:0` for the content area to cover the whole screen, when in `landscape mode` the safari navigation bar will cover the bottom of the content and you cannot scroll past it - it does NOT block in portrait.

1. portrait mode is fine, even when navigation bar is there
2. it's not an orientation change bug, happens if page is started in landscape
3. bug does NOT happen if the webpage is added to the homescreen, works perfect in landscape and content is visible (because navigation is not there)

So why does safari get `bottom:0` correct in portrait but not landscape?

Comment: Can't believe no-ones run into this yet - good old Safari!

Answer (score 9):

setting `position:fixed` on the `html` element magically fixed this

`html { position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden; }`

not sure why but must be a rendering bug that `fixed` works around

for some reason `fixed` also change the font size in landscape but I can work around that too

Comment: That worked for me and in our situation. Even though it might not work for others.

Comment: Great solution! Was stuck with this several hours.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem, on orientation change if its in `landscape` mode, change your `viewport` meta to:

```
width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no
```

I'm doing this by simply finding `$('meta[name="viewport"]')` and replacing its `content`.